# Method or Data Member not found error in excel VBA 2016

Tags: excel, vba

When I run the following code it throws a compile error:

> Method or data member not found

and highlights `.tv_Hierarchy`.

[image]

Even defining `Option Explicit` in the beginning still it throws the same error.

The entire code.

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Dim OTvw As TreeView
Dim oNode As Node
Dim sStartMember As String
Dim sDimension As String
Dim DimMembers As Collection
Dim HierMembers As Collection    

Private Sub lbx_MemData_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

Dim sMemberKey As String

'Show the duplicate member in the hierarchy
If Me.lbx_MemData.List(1, 1) = "Duplicate Member" Then
    If Left(Me.lbx_MemData.value, 11) = "Hier Parent" Then
        Cancel = True
        sMemberKey = Me.lbx_MemData.List(Me.lbx_MemData.ListIndex, 1)
        Me.tv_Hierarchy.SetFocus
        Me.tv_Hierarchy.nodes.Item(sMemberKey).Selected = True
    End If
End If

ExitHere:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
Select Case Err
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Error # " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Error$, 
vbExclamation, AddInShortName + " - LbxMemDatDblCli"
        Resume ExitHere:
End Select

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

'Dim
Dim oDim As proCubeApi.Dimension

'Init performed?
If bInit = True Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'Initialise
Set OTvw = Me.tv_Hierarchy

'Refresh User Selections
Me.cbx_Dimension.Clear
Me.tbx_Member.Text = ""

'Refresh Form
ClearForm

'Mark the dimension members to clear
KeepDimMembers = False

'Setup proCube Connection
If ModproCubeAPI.CreateDBConnection(dbs, DB) = False Then
    Me.Hide
    Exit Sub
End If

'Validate as admin Group
If Mod_Util_Sec.IsMemberOfGroup("Plc appadmin") = False Then
    MsgBox "You could not be validated as part of the security group responsible for applicagtion administration. The administrator must add you as part of this group before you may proceed.", vbCritical
    Me.Hide
    Exit Sub
End If

'Add all dimensions to dimension selector
For Each oDim In DB.Dimensions
    Me.cbx_Dimension.AddItem (oDim.Name)
Next oDim

'Init True
bInit = True

ExitHere:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
Select Case Err
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Error # " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Error$, 
vbExclamation, AddInShortName + " - UseForAct"
        Resume ExitHere:
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: This error has the following causes and solutions:
1- You misspelled the object or member name. Check the spelling of the names and check the Type statement or the object documentation to determine what the members are and the proper spelling of the object or member names.
2- You specified a collection index that's out of range. Check the Count property to determine whether a collection member exists. Note that collection indexes begin at 1 rather than zero, so the Count property returns the highest possible index number.

Comment: What is tv_hiearchy and does it have the member (method) SetFocus?